# Designing band pass filter in UHF range

Tags: filter

I need a band-pass filter (simple or Butterworth with order 1 or more)   to operate around 538 MHz with 8MHz BW and Gain around 1dB. I am planning to design the filter using general purpose opamp like 741. What are the constraints and precautions needed during operation in UHF range. Any other cheap and simple ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the UHF frequencies, the resistance values used with the opamp would be fairly low and design could be an issue . However at around 580MHz, the design should  be fairly easy. Try out on a circuit simulator before the actual built.